How to fill the remaining space in LazyColumn Jetpack Compose?
I have a LazyColumn that contains 3 items:
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    item {
        Text("Some text..."}
        Text("Some text..."}
    }
    item {
        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        )
        Text("Copyright © Max 2024")
    }
}

My aim is to place the "Copyright..." text at the bottom of the screen. The problem is that I cannot use a Spacer with Modifier.weight(1f). How can I solve this problem without using a Column?

cant you move the Text("Copyright © Max 2024") outside ?

@GauravRoy Outside what? If I put it after the last item, I get @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function, if I put it outside the LazyColumn doesn't work at all. So how to solve this?

i mean, outside lazyColumn, sorry didnt communicate that earlier

@GauravRoy As I mentioned earlier, if I put it outside the LazyColumn doesn't work at all.

@AlwaysLearner I hope you are composing every view in different item means you will have more than two items right ? If that's not the case means you will only have two items as shown in code then you can simply use verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween for LazyColumn.

@AtulSharma Can show me an example? All I want is to have some text and the text to be placed at te bottom of the screen.

@AlwaysLearner My question is that "Are there only two items always in LazyColumn or more than two ?"

@AtulSharma There are two items + one last item.

@AlwaysLearner Now I understand but as per your code sample there is only two items any composable in item {} lambda is treated as a sigle item only for LazyLayouts no matter how many composable are there inside one item and when you use items then it will compose every item separately. Now according to your need there can be any number of items in your LazyColumn.

@AtulSharma So how to solve this?

You can refer my answer for creating a custom Arrangment that puts last item to bottom no matter how many items

@AlwaysLearner Actually your question is not straight to the point you should edit it in proper way explaining all the cases. As If you want the copyright text always present on the screen then I don't understand what is the problem in use of column. And if you want the copyright text should also be scrollable with other items if they are large in numbers and if there are just few items then the copyright text should be at bottom by filling the empty space if that's the case then you can also refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/77350789/14972910. This might help you achieve your challenge.

You can use your custom Arrangment for this that places last item to bottom.
Result

Code
val ArrangementLazyColumnLastItemToBottom = object : Arrangement.Vertical {
    override fun Density.arrange(totalSize: Int, sizes: IntArray, outPositions: IntArray) {
        var consumedHeight = 0
        sizes.forEachIndexed { index, height ->
            if (index == sizes.lastIndex) {
                // If it's last item position at the bottom
                outPositions[index] = totalSize - height
            } else {
                // If not last item position below other
                outPositions[index] = consumedHeight
                consumedHeight += height
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun LazyColumnArrangmentTest() {

    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().border(2.dp, Color.Red),
        verticalArrangement = ArrangementLazyColumnLastItemToBottom
    ) {
        item {
            Text("Text1")
        }
        item {
            Text("Text2")
        }

        item {
            Text("Text3")
        }

        item {
            Text("Text4")
        }
        item {
            Text("Text5")
        }

        item {
            Text("Footer")
        }
    }
}


Let me try and get back to you. Thank you for the answer.

This solution put the footer text at center of the remaining empty space. But this https://stackoverflow.com/a/77350789/14972910 solution can make it at the bottom of empty space.

I tested this and it doesn't put it center of empty space. It puts bottom of the available space because outPositions[index] = totalSize - consumedHeight. totalSize is the bottom of the Composable that uses this arrangment

It should be -height tough not consumedHeight

@Thracian No it's not working. The footer composable left the space which the upper items consumed. You can just see the perfect result becuase you have only two upper itesm try it with more items.

@Thracian Now its working with edit outPositions[index] = totalSize - height. But before that it was causing same effect I have mentioned.

I know, that's what i posted in comment after that. You are right it wasn't correct but it wasn't centering in remaining space. It was using height of other items that were placed

you can always move the Text("Copyright © Max 2024"), "Outside"
Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        ) {
            item {
                Text("Some text...")
                Text("Some text...")
            }
        }

        Text("Copyright © Max 2024")
    }
   


As I mentioned in a comment, if I put it outside the LazyColum doesn't work at all.

@AlwaysLearner would you provide the parent of lazycolumn, so we can properly answer?

The parent of the LazyColum is Surface.

screenshot you can see the image link i show you, it should work properly @AlwaysLearner

I mentioned in my question, How can I solve this problem without using a Column?. I use a LazyColumn. Thanks anyway.

So i see the problem, but if you want to achieve maximum performance.
LazyColumn is not a magical way to make everything optimize.
it's like make every ui is recyclerview, which is over engineering and chaos to maintain.
In my experience, compose is not that heavy, even you put Column inside LazyColumn.
The most important for performance in compose how you manage state.
But if you still want to challenge yourself to achieve this, you can always try to get the height of the screen and calculate the the filled ui to bottom text, which i don't know how to code it.

UPDATE:
 val screenHeight = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp


Surface(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(1f)
    ) {
        item {
            Text("Some text...")
            Text("Some text...")
        }
    }

    Text("Copyright © Max 2024", modifier = Modifier.offset(y = screenHeight.dp-90.dp))
}

so what we can do is use offest, if you want it the bottom.
Note: currently i have bottom tab thats why ive added -90.dp , try without that. it should work @AlwaysLearner
Please post the entire UI structure


I mentioned in my question, How can I solve this problem without using a Column?. I use a LazyColumn. Thanks anyway.

@AlwaysLearner ive updated it

How about when the screen is higher? Will -90.dp apply as well?

what do you mean by higher? try without -90 dp, if that works, otherwise adjust as per + or - some dp

cool, glad it helped. do accept as correct if you think its correct
